# Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Whenever I try to use any package which allows multiple selection of images/files, this error shows up : 
**Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.**

I tried doing multiDexEnabled: true but still no good.

There's no point of putting up the code here because this error shows up even if I only import that package and perform run-android.

Packages tried:
react-native-image-crop-picker
react-native-customized-image-picker
react-native-document-picker

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this command

```
Go to your root folder, android -> ./gradlew clean 

or


android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```